# Integrity error with Django models (NOT NULL constraint failed)

Tags: python, django

can someone please help with the below error? I get the error when I am trying to update my models database.

IntegrityError at /configuration/solarwinds/
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_cityname.name
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_cityname.name
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

Here is my models.py:

Basically, whenever I select a "Region", there should be a dependent dropdown update to the "Cityname" dropdown. So there is a foreign key relationship between Region and Cityname.

```
class Region(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Region'


class Cityname(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cityname'


class SolarwindsTool(models.Model):

    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='Region')

    city = models.ForeignKey(Cityname, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='City')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'solarwindstool'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the relevant code under views.py:

```
myvar = {'Data Centers': ['LAX101', 'LAX100', 'EWR100'], 'Americas': ['MEX01', 'BOU02', 'TOR01', 'LAX55']}

    for key in sorted(myvar):
        if Region.objects.filter(name = key).exists():
            for items in myvar[key]:
                if Cityname.objects.filter(name = items).exists():
                    pass
                else:
                    # value = Site(name=key)
                    b=Region.objects.get(name=key)
                    # print(b)
                    e=Cityname(region=b,name=items)
                    e.save()
                 

        else:
            value = Region(name=key)
            value.save()
            print("THIS IS SITE",key)
            for items in myvar[key]:
                # v = Site.objects.filter(site__name__contains=key)
                value2 = Cityname(name=items,region=value)
                print("THIS IS VALUE2", value2)
                value2.save()
```

Comment: Show us the view code for the `/configuration/solarwinds/` url.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon, please check my update and provide help.

Comment: You are doing a lot of database queries here. These can be very expensive as your database grows larger. The first improvement I see you can make is to keep the result of `Region.objects.filter(name = key)` so that you avoid executing basically the same query again later with `Region.objects.get(name=key)`. With some work, you might even be able leverage the database to do more work for you, and more efficiently, with a more complex query that removes the need for a manual `for` loop.

Comment: With that, I recommend that you use more descriptive variable names. `myvar`, `b`, `e`, `value` and `value2` tell you nothing about what each of these variables represent.

Comment: thanks, those are some valuable feedback. Room for some improvement in code quality.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was this:

I was trying to write a "None" value in my models database and that's something django didn't like. So, I only put the following condition that fixed the issue:

from this:

```
                b=Region.objects.get(name=key)
                    # print(b)
                e=Cityname(region=b,name=items)
                e.save()
```

to this:

```
                b=Region.objects.get(name=key)
                    # print(b)
                if items is not None:
                    e=Cityname(region=b,name=items)
                    e.save()
```

Comment: Why is `items` ever `None`? You might have a deeper problem here that you should look into.